# How to configure a wildcard DNS (ie. `.dev`) with systemd components (systemd-networkd)?

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, systemd

I would love to have the `*.dev` tld available as it is possible with `dnsmasq`.
When I look for tutorials to have `*.dev` domains pointing to the local machine I just find stuff about how to replace the system resolve stuff with `dnsmasq` again (or even use a distribution that moved away from systemd).

PS: The last time I tried to have `dnsmasq` installed together with the systemd components I had a heavy CPU load and I guess it doesn't make sense to have more than one DNS resolver running anyway so this question is clearly about using `systemd` components *only*.

Comment: Ah, nevermind. It looks as there is indeed [no support for DNS wildcards](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6081).